# What is the new "Actions" button in Chrome for?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

It looks like a plus (+) symbol and when I click it nothing happens.

Here's a screenshot. Notice the "+" button inside the address bar:

[image]

Open the screenshot in a new tab to see the full size.

Hovering over the button makes it darker, implying it's a button (or that it does something) and the tooltip says "Actions".

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @ForceFlow I've added a screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had it in the development branch for a while, and it's apparently where they're trying to move the "Bookmark this page", and things such as that. If I'm not mistaken, it can be disabled in `about:flags` in the stable/beta versions of Chrome.

The name of the flag is "Action box".

As of `Chrome 23.0.1271.10 (Official Build 158896) dev`, this box shows:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That was it. I'm using Chromium 22 (stable I believe) and there's no box at all. Nothing happens when I click it. Also, disabling Action Box restored the missing Browser Action buttons for my extensions. I guess I'll try it out again when Chrome 23 reaches stable.

Comment: Yeah. They added it in as an experiment a few versions back in the development branch, and it didn't have a box when they first added it. I want to say it was right before it went to version 22.x.